# Flutter - when redirect to a WebView, this shows a blank page

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, flutter-routes

After login (native flutter) I would like the user to be taken back to a WebView screen.

The screen is within a router route but doing something like `context.go('/web')` I am brought back to a blank page in Android, while on iOS it is correctly shown, even if it is impossible to click on it.

Is it possible to be redirected to a WebView?